# Create a 3D cone in Illustrator with rainbow colors

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color, 3d, gradient

**Problem:**

To create a 3D cone with a rainbow spectrum that consist of 24 colors. Example of the final product should look like this:

[image]

**Example #1 (what I have done so far):**

1. Create a circle and use the Line Segment Tool to divide it in half.

[image]

2. Divide the circle into 24 parts (**Effect -> Distort & Transform -> Transform**)
3. Set angle at 15 degrees and make 25 copies.

[image]

4. I clicked **Object -> Expand Appearance**.
5. I grouped all parts together and used **Pathfinder -> Divide** and then ungrouped all parts.

[image]

6. I copied over some of the colors from the first picture using V and I to shift between select and Eyedropper Tool.
7. The result became a rainbow circle and this is where I got stuck.

[image]

**Desired outcome:**

How do I proceed to take the circle rainbow and transform it into a 3D cone with gradient effect for the green and blue colors?

Comment: You do not have any gradient yet.

Comment: @Rafael I was thinking of adding the gradient for the colors green and blue because these are the only ones visible in the cone.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I can suggest a method to make the cone, but I think the gradients will probably have to be created manually. I can't really think of a quick way of doing them. Sorry about that.

Anyway, here goes:

1. Select the circle and squish it into an oval
2. Copy it, paste in front, and group the copy
3. Hide the group
4. Use the Lasso Tool to select the middle anchors
5. Using the Direct Selection tool, click and drag the middle anchors down to make the cone
6. Unhide the group you previously hid.
7. From the centre outwards, select each section of the cone in turn, and do *Object > Arrange > Send to Back*. You can also use the keyboard shortcut for this: <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl/Command</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd>

Example

[image]

Comment: Appreciate your time, this is what I was looking for. I do not mind doing manual work.

Comment: instead of sending to back why not just delete? Those shapes won't be used and just add clutter.

Comment: @Luciano - yes, you could since they are hidden anyway.